# speed boost for just a subdomain

Tags: cdn

Because I'm hesitant to jump into new products for my website, I'm looking for a special free CDN that I don't know if it exists or not.

I tried incapsula on my mobile site, and unfortunately, it adds a logo at the bottom right which I believe my mobile users would find as an annoyance and google might get mad since I'm running adsense on the same site.

I looked into cloudflare, but it only works on entire domain names, not just a single sub-domain.

Is there another free CDN that allows me to test just a single sub-domain on their network to see if their service works well before throwing my whole domain into them? If so, which is the best one?